# Merging overlapping thematic rasters using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, overlay, reclassify

I want to merge two overlapping rasters. Raster A has 8 classes and raster B has only 1 class. I would like to produce Raster C with 9 classes, where Raster B would overwrite corresponding pixels in Raster A. I tried using the "raster merge" function in QGIS, but it does not produce what I want.

How do I do this in ArcMap?

[image: A=8 classes, B = 1 class, C 9 classes]

Comment: How about giving a try with Mosaic to New Raster tool in ArcMap https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, The Mosaic tool solved my problem